# vscode creates terminal popups

Tags: terminal, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I have been using vscode for a while for various projects, but recently when I open it a bunch of terminals pop up with it. There's maybe 7 total that pop up one at a time but they disappear too quickly for me to see what they say. I don't know what I would have changed to create this issue or how to fix it. Anyone have any ideas?

It happens no matter where I open vscode from, and I'm talking about external command lines, not the one built into vscode.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your issue?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your issue? -> "they disappear too quickly"

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is for installing additional dependencies. Some of the extensions need e.g. plaform specific binaries (native libraries, written in C++ and precompiled). The usual approach for the installation is then to have only the core in the market place and on activation on the users side additional parts are downloaded.

You can see that e.g. with the C# extension (C++ too), however I haven't seen any of them using an external terminal (their output goes to the internal terminal window). But I can imagine other externsions do it that way.